# Test Complete on Citrix

Tags: automated-tests, testng, integration-testing, microsoft-dynamics, citrix

I am trying to automate Microsoft AX interface which is located on  citrix/xenapp on a remote server ,

I have being looking to use the test-complete tool mainly because I want a tool that will do the following:

1. A normal user can use it (i.e. no coding).
2. Does it provide a nice easy to use GUI that allows you to structure tests in a logical manner
3. I can use it with AX via citrix login
4. I can pull data from a database to make testing more dynamic
5. I can scale this up across multiple “servers”/”node” to conduct performance testing

Regards
Bongani

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: my Question is how do i go about creating a TestComplete on citrix  ? may you help ?

Comment: taking inconsideration the requirements i stated above.